# Upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 19.10

I have Matlab installed in the /bin directory of Ubuntu 19.10. If I upgrade to 20.04 will Matlab be erased?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded feom 19.10 to 20.04.1 and matlab (2017b) remained intact. No need to reinstall or anything.

Comment: Thank you, very useful to know ...